# Node / Express parsed JSON POST is not valid JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am making a JSON POST request using Pure Javascript XMLHttpRequest, however Express appears to wrap the received JSON in an additional object, how can I prevent this ?

I am using the bodyParser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

This is the client sending the JSON data:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://xxx.my.net/",true);

// This header MUST be present for POST requests.
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"hxx":1}));
```

And this is Nodejs / Express middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    fn.console.log(req.body);
   })
```

This is the console.log output:

```
   { '{"hxx":1}': '' }
```

I know that I can parse the body with:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]))
```

but I would prefer not to have to do this !

## IMPORTANT Note

I have already tried using content type = "application/json" but when I do this the request becomes a GET instead of a POST, and Unless I state "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" the request is automatically converted by the browser from a POST to a GET.

Comment: why `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then ?

Comment: Set your content type to application/json rather than urlencoded, and make sure you're using the bodyParser.json() middleware on the server.

Comment: Can't set to 'application/json' because then the POST gets automatically converted to a GET

Comment: Try set content-type to application/json and then enable cors in the server side if you're using xmlhttprequest. Follow this tutorial https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: Thanks, cors is enabled already, if you set application/json then the browser converts the POST into a GET request. The problems is not that the request is not received, the problem is express is converting the received JSON into a object key.